How to read the data on these drives?


I've got these drives from an old computer. I need to access the data inside. I've scoured the internet looking for an adapter, but it doesn't seem to exists. So how do I get to the data on them?

What did you search for? Its SCSI 3 - and a quick google search suggests while a little pricy, there seem to be PCI and PCIe cards for it as well as cables. Its going to be somewhat pricy and I don't know if you need, say a terminator for these

I kind of think this is a question for [retrocomputing.se] as there aren't really any modern "pure" SCSI systems. It's all SAS and SATA now. Check out https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/scsi-to-usb-interface and https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/634/79 and https://www.google.com/search?q=modern+scsi+site:retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

@JourneymanGeek I did order one of those, but its too large. Mine seems to be a special version, as it requires a male adapter and a smaller connector

@Mokubai its a 68 pin

@DrMoishePippik I can't find a femal 68 pin there
